# Delphi REST.client E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'rmPost'

Tags: delphi

I do

```
RESTRequest1.Method := rmPost;
```

I get

E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'rmPost'

REST.Client is in the use clause.

Comment: Because you have to assign `rmPost` to something first.

Comment: @Zydnar I have no idea what you mean with you comment. As the answer below states, `REST.Types` needs to be in the `uses` clause for it to be found.

Comment: @JerryDodge As you can see my comment was as old as the answer, so I coudn't refer to answer didn't exist. After doing most trivial google search I found rmPost is to be found in REST.Types so if I can find it I assumed OP already did that and problem is somwhere else.

Comment: @Zydnar Sure, but either way, what you state makes no sense. OP IS trying to assign `rmPost` to something.

Comment: Ok, my mistake I meant declare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `REST.Types` to the `uses` clause.